# How can Iist current user record on a select list in views in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I list records that belong to the currently logged in user as a select list?

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :offices, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :staffs, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```rb
class Office < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :staffs, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```rb
class Staff < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I tried the code below but still will have all offices listed instead of the current user's created offices available for selection

```
 <%= f.association :office,  label_method: :office_name, value_method: :user, include_blank: false, prompt: "Assign Staff To Office" %>
```

My expectations are that only offices created by the current user will be listed in the select list item on the staff creation form

Comment: Are you using Devise to get the current user? you can use current_user.offices as the collection for the select form helper

Comment: yes, I am using devise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a collection select like this

```
<%= f.collection_select(:office_id, current_user.offices, :id, :name) %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tony it worked! here is how i modified your suggestions to solve the problem <%= f.collection_select(:office_id, current_user.offices, :id, :office_name) %>